# Live JavaScript edit in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, developer-tools

In Chrome this is possible, but I don't find a way to do it in Safari.
Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.

Comment: Now it is 2018, so... is it still not possible?

Comment: @JosephK. Now it is 2019, so... is it still not possible?

Comment: Now it is 2020, so... is it still not possible?

Comment: As of April 2020, this is now possible in Safari! https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/

Answer (score 8):

As of April 2020, this is now possible in Safari!

https://webkit.org/web-inspector/local-overrides/

Comment: It's not executing according to the local overriden code though. Are there any additional steps required in order to do that?

Answer (score 5):

The closest option is to pause JavaScript and execute commands from the console.

To open Safari dev tools, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> Mac. Or enable Safari dev commands in the menubar in Safari Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop Menu.

See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/1Introduction/Introduction.html) on how to use its dev tools.

Unlike in Chrome, the Safari debugger does not currently support the ability to click on a script file and edit it in place. However, you can still stop execution using break points or the pause button, then execute code in the console to alter values, then resume execution.

For example, if you have the code:

```
var t = 1;
(function(){
    var t = 2;
    console.log(t);  //* put break point on this line..    
})();
console.log(t);
```

And you but a break point where indicated, then run `t = 4` in the console, the value `4` then `1` are printed to the console.

Comment: Well, I was able to edit the JS in Chrome but not in Safari. That's why I made this question.

Comment: Right got it, sorry I thought you wanted to execute JS live on the page, not change the loaded scripts.  No, I don't think you can currently do that.  Probably, the best you can do is to use the console to alter the JavaScript to alter the values of the variables that the code calls.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: Pressing command-option-c opens the Safari console, not the Safari Debugger, in version 11.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Although both chrome and safari use webkit as their engine, chrome makes its own customizations and additions over it. Live editing of javascript seems to be one of them.

If you look closely the debugging panels in chrome and safari have many other differences as well. A clearly visible change is settings icon present in chrome and thats not available in safari.

Answer (score -1):

Try in Safari Technology Preview 15.4:

```
console.log("I'm live!");
```

It outputs

```
> "I'm live!"
```