# modify javascript before it gets executed by Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, liveedit

I read some old questions about Live Edit in Safari. There was an option to set a breakpoint, double click on the line and edit the code. I am double clicking the code right now, but no luck. How can I edit the javascript code before it gets executed in Safari? Through extensions or in some other way?

Comment: Did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787209/2873538)?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but console is only great for global variables. What can you do about variables defined in a specific scope?

Comment: You are right. But you can access local variables if you put breakpoints in their scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In safari, it is not possible to edit the javascript code as you do in other browsers (e.g. chrome). But you can **modify** the variable values using Developer Tools in safari (to open: `ATL+CTRL+C` or `Command+Option+C` on Mac). All you need to do is apply **breakpoints** at appropriate lines and modify the variables using **console** in Developer Tools.